# Silently ignore image not found

Tags: html, image, browser

I have a image tag like this:

```
<img src='<? path_to_png_image ?>' id=submit />
```

The image is actually picked up based on the user. It is possible that the user is configured not to have an image. In such a case, I don't want to see the link/image broken image on the page. Also can I prevent the browser from reporting the resource not found error in the console?

Am I ignorant asking this? Your help appreciated.

Regards
Vivek Ragunathan

Comment: How are you rendering this image tag on the page? I'm assuming PHP based on the <? ... ?> placeholder?

Comment: Yep. constructing the page using PHP!

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code to give some context? You could either check for a null/empty string in the path_to_png_image and not render the image tag at all, or specify your own default image instead. That way you can avoid adding presentation logic into your PHP code, and potentially give your user a nicer experience.

Comment: @DanielAttfield Thanks, I believe that is the simplest thing to do.